# Efficient way of counting through categorical data values and printing to excel

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a probably very basic question, but cannot figure out the necessary control structures in R, as I am pretty new to R programming.

The situation is as follows:

I have a data.frame with ten factor variables which have 4 levels each (very important - not important). Now I want to count through the occurences of levels in each variable and put them in a new dataframe. Which should then look something like this:

```
            Var1    Var2   etc.. 
Important   78      ...
....        12      ...
....        4       ... 
Unimportant 0       etc.
```

As of now, I can only think about counting each of the original variables with count() from the plyr package and then somehow cbind() the columns together. However, this would require a lot of typing work and I cannot suppress the feeling that there must be a better way to solve this in R.

However, I can't figure out the necessary commands for this in R as I am pretty new to R programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
data.frame(sapply(your.dataframe, function(x) { summary(x) }))
```

`summary()` is a magical little `R` function which will give you the number of occurrences of each factor level in an input vector (or data frame column in this case).

I will also note that this solution will only work if each column in `your.dataframe` has the same number of factors (which is true and equal to 4 in your original problem).